# How can I start a script in Exchange Management Shell from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I am creating a website with which you can create room mailboxes. Once you click on "Create", a PowerShell-Script is built in C# (as a string). Now how do I start the Exchange Management Shell and execute that script?

I've tried 
`Process.Start(EMSfilePath, scriptToBeExecuted)`, however the EMS is a shortcut (.lnk file) and Process.Start doesn't like that. When I look at the target of that shortcut I see that powershell.exe is started with a couple of parameters. If I try   `Process.Start("powershell.exe", coupleOfParameters`), the EMS does get opened, however I don't know how to now pass my script in there. Please help

Comment: You can execute PowerShell code directly from C# using the [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=pscore-6.2.0) class.  I've never tried any Exchange-related scripts that way, but it's worth a look.

Comment: Yeah I'm looking at that right now, but it says that the api-ms-win-eventing-provider-l1-1-0.dll is missing and if I try to add that dll it says "the reference is invalid or unsupported".

Comment: Office 365 or on premise Exchange servers?

Answer (score 0):

I've used this C# example code in the past to manage on-premises Exchange Server:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Security;


private static Runspace OpenExchangeManagementRunspace(
    string url,
    AuthenticationMechanism authenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos,
    string userName = null,
    string password = null)
{
    Runspace runspace = null;

    WSManConnectionInfo shellConnection = null;

    PSCredential shellCred = null;

    // Username and password is optional when using Kerberos authentication
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
    {
        var securePassword = ConvertToSecureString(password);
        shellCred = new PSCredential(userName, securePassword);
    }

    shellConnection = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(url), "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", shellCred);

    shellConnection.AuthenticationMechanism = authenticationMechanism;

    // This will take some time
    runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(shellConnection);
    runspace.Open();

    return runspace;
}


// USAGE:


// URL for Office365:
//     https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/
//
// URL for on-premises Exchange server:
//     http://hostname/powershell?serializationLevel=Full;clientApplication=MyAppName
//
using (Runspace remoteRunspace = OpenExchangeManagementRunspace("https://example.com/powershell?serializationLevel=Full;clientApplication=MyExampleAppName"))
using (PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    shell.Runspace = remoteRunspace;

    // Run some commands:
    shell
        .AddCommand("Get-Mailbox")
        .AddParameter("Identity", "example@example.com")
        .Invoke();
}
```